# How to avoid error in mutate different size in r?

Tags: r

Given this data.frame:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), X2=seq(0,200,by=10)[-1])
  df2 <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), X2=seq(0,200,by=10)[-1])
   df1$Source = "df1"
   df2$Source = "df2"
   dfc = rbind(df1, df2)
   out <- dfc %>%
   filter(X2 <= 1000) %>%
   group_by(Source) %>%
   mutate(
    X2 = diff(X2),
    X1 = diff(X1)
)

 I got this error

        Error in `mutate()`:
        ℹ In argument: `X2 = diff(X2)`.
        ℹ In group 1: `Source = "df1"`.
        Caused by error:
         ! `X2` must be size 21 or 1, not 20.
```

Comment: Where is the difference to the question you posted and deleted before?

Comment: I think you need to internalize that a `data.frame` must always have the same length for all of its columns; this is true when you want to `mutate` it, and it is also true when you _create_ it. After we replace the never-should-be-used `data.frame(cbind(...))` with just `data.frame(...)`, we can see that your `rnorm(..)` is length 20 and your `seq` is length 21. You should be getting clear warnings when creating this sample data, and while _some_ warnings are okay to ignore, you really need to know what the warning is saying, know that it is not a concern, before ignoring it. Here, not safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things to work on.

1. (Almost) "Never" use `data.frame(cbind(...))`. At best, it's just code-golf longer while providing zero benefit or convenience. If any of your columns are a different class than the others (e.g., `character` and `numeric`, or `integer` and `logical`), they will be coerced, meaning numbers will be strings, etc. Yes, you can hack it back to numbers, but this *can be lossy* in some cases and should not be required.

   Just do `data.frame(...)`.
2. Your columns are different lengths. If this is a matter of your fake data, then you should really "try to use" your own data that you ask us to use. If this is your real data, then ...

   There are some warnings in R that, once you understand what they *mean*, you are mostly safe to ignore them. However, you really need to know the warning. In your case, your sample data is saying that the columns are different lengths, which means something is being recycled (in a way that R should never have allowed, imho). I'll modify your sample data to remove the warnings so that we know what the data really is, since it is clear that one of each frame's columns is not what you intend.
3. The since-deleted R-canonical answer is to pad the results of `diff` with an `NA`, either before or after (which depends on your use). With `diff`, you should never need to pad with anything more than 1 `NA`. If you are using a different function instead of `diff`, then I suggest it may (though not certainly) be best to create a new frame.

   Older versions of `dplyr` allowed `summarize` to return different numbers of rows, but the preferred mechanism now is `dplyr::reframe`.

Updated sample data.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(20,0.4,0.2), X2=seq(0,199,by=10))
df2 <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(30,0.6,0.25), X2=seq(0,269,by=9))
dfc <- bind_rows(lst(df1, df2), .id="Source")
head(dfc)
#   Source        X1 X2
# 1    df1 0.4643851  0
# 2    df1 0.2432322 10
# 3    df1 0.7151455 20
# 4    df1 0.5285799 30
# 5    df1 0.4179521 40
# 6    df1 0.4553101 50
```

Code:

```r
dfc %>%
  filter(X2 <= 1000) %>%
  group_by(Source) %>%
  reframe(X2 = diff(X2), X1 = diff(X1))
# # A tibble: 48 × 3
#    Source    X2      X1
#    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 df1       10 -0.221 
#  2 df1       10  0.472 
#  3 df1       10 -0.187 
#  4 df1       10 -0.111 
#  5 df1       10  0.0374
#  6 df1       10  0.0805
#  7 df1       10 -0.118 
#  8 df1       10 -0.617 
#  9 df1       10  0.656 
# 10 df1       10 -0.130 
# # ℹ 38 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

If you have more columns, it might be easier to use `across`. Also, unless you need the grouping in the follow-on operation(s), I suggest the use of `.by=` (only available in `dplyr_1.1.0` and newer) instead of grouping (and then ungrouping).

```r
dfc %>%
  filter(X2 <= 1000) %>%
  reframe(.by = Source, across(c(X1, X2), ~ diff(.x))) %>%
  head()
#   Source          X1 X2
# 1    df1 -0.22115284 10
# 2    df1  0.47191329 10
# 3    df1 -0.18656564 10
# 4    df1 -0.11062773 10
# 5    df1  0.03735802 10
# 6    df1  0.08054761 10
```

Note that while `nrow(dfc)` is 50, the results have 48 rows. No warnings about different numbers of rows :-)